# Cutting FLAC using ffmpeg does not change timestamps accordingly

Tags: ffmpeg, flac

I am using the following command to cut a FLAC file:

`ffmpeg -i input.flac -ss 10s -t 10s -c copy output.flac`

`output.flac` contains the correct duration of audio. However, all media players show its duration as the duration of `input.flac`.

The only other mention of this issue is an open [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4905) from 5 years ago.

How do I correct the timestamp of the output file?

Answer (score 4):

A suboptimal workaround is to re-encode by removing `-c copy`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -ss 10 -t 10 output.flac
```

Since FLAC is lossless there will be no quality loss, but it will take longer than stream copying.